# F# FSI and .Net Core. Can't find the right System.Runtime.dll

Tags: .net-core, f#, fsi

I'm trying to start a .net core app within fsi but I keep getting this error.  I tried `#r "{the right System.Runtime}"` but it still fails.  Any ideas?

```
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationReloadToken.RegisterChangeCallback(Action`1 callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.ChangeTokenRegistration`1.RegisterChangeTokenCallback(IChangeToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildHostConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at FSI_0002.Fsi_util.FSU.start_fsi@116.Invoke(Unit unitVar) in C:\Test\Scripts\util.fsx:line 133
```

Comment: Is this in Vscode? On what OS?

Comment: it's in visual studio 2019 on win10